# PHP: Is it possible to use GetElementById on another PHP file?

Tags: php, html, getelementbyid

I have a very complicated PHP file which generates a lot of HTML, but I'm interested in extracting only some of it (within the `<div id="content">` element) to another file.  The thing is, that element is generated by the PHP.

Is it possible to use PHP's native [`getElementById`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php) function to get the `content` element from another PHP file?  Or even from within itself?

For example, something like this, but actually working:

```
$doc = new DomDocument;

// We need to validate our document before referring to the id
$doc->validateOnParse = true;
$doc->Load('file.php');

echo "The contents are: ".$doc->getElementById('content')->textContent;
```

I realize this would mean the PHP will have to be executed to generate the HTML, which could be why the answer is simply *No, this is not possible* and I also realize this would mean a lot of additional run time.  I'm not worried about those at the moment, just if this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
ob_start()
include 'file.php';
$html = ob_get_clean();

$doc = new DomDocument;

// We need to validate our document before referring to the id
$doc->validateOnParse = true;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
```

Comment: Don't know why I did not think of include :| way better than my answer

Answer (score 0):

->Load wont 'execute' the PHP file, it will see the raw source, which probably wont be much use.

You can possibly use the http wrapper, functionality - that actully fetches the page over the web.
http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php

Because it's via the web, the php is executed by the web-server as normal.

```
 $doc->Load('http://your-domain.com/path/to/file.php');
```

But not very efficient.

(there are other ways to execute the file - perhaps using shell_exec. Or can just 'include' the file, after wrapping it in output buffering. But the above is the quickest way)

Answer (score 0):

This should work, I think.

```
// init the CURL
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // we do not want to process the headers later
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); // return response as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'www.mywebsite.com/file.php'); // the URL

// execute the curl
// this will basically call the URL and your PHP will execute as intended
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// use loadHTML() here
$doc->loadHTML($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $doc->**loadHTMLFile**('file.php'); if your file.php generate in output some HTML and use 
$elems = $doc->getElementById('content');

and do a foreach on the nodes ;)

somes exemples here : http://php.net/manual/fr/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php

Edit : See test.php call test2.php

**test.php**

```
<?php
$doc = new DomDocument;
$doc->loadHTMLFile('test2.php');
$element = $doc->getElementById('tested')->textContent;
print_r($element);
?>
```

**test2.php**

```
<?php
echo"
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id='tested'>texte ok</div>
</body>
</html>";
?>
```

and its work :)

Comment: This will actually executed the PHP file and generate the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

what you could do is edit the complex file adding:

```
ob_start()
```

at the top and

```
$contents = ob_get_clean();
```

at the end

Then something like:

```
if(isset($_GET['getLimitedContent'])){
   $doc = new \DomDocument;
   $doc->loadHTML($contents);
   // parse out and echo the required elements
}else{
   echo $contents;
}
```